# When will I get my Federal refund if I file today, given the deadline has been extended to July 15th?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, income-tax-refund, covid-19

Due to the covid-19 pandemic, the Federal government has decided to extend its tax filing and payment deadline to July 15th. So, if I were to file today, will I get my refund check in the mail this month or will I not get it until after July 15th? I'd like to get it sooner than latter (of course). I am within the United States. I plan to e-file through an online service like CreditKarma or TurboTax.

Comment: Are you e-filing or mailing it in?

Comment: @Joe I will be e-filing through an online service.

Comment: Anecdotally I filed my taxes on 3/28 through Credit Karma Tax and received my refund on 4/2.  The turn around with e-filed federal taxes should just be a work week assuming yours are accepted immediately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally the IRS processes your return as soon as they can. So unless there is an issue that causes them to have to stop processing returns you will get your refund in a few weeks. It does depend on direct deposit vs paper check.

Usually each year they set a date in January or February when they will start processing returns, but if you file after that date they will get to them as quickly as possible.

People who are due a refund generally file early to get their money earlier. Those that owe tend to file at the last minute.

Comment: One caveat to the general rule: since 2016 if you efile early (soon after processing opens) _and_ claim **EITC and/or ACTC** IRS [must hold your refund until Feb. 15](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/refund-timing) and in practice it seems to run 1-2 weeks after that. But for this Q we are well past Feb. 15.

Answer (score 10):

The sooner you file your tax return, the sooner you’ll get your refund. This has not changed, and there has been no talk of delaying tax refund payments.

Answer (score 4):

I filed electronically on March 22 and received the refund (direct deposit) 7 days later.

Answer (score 0):

Update. I have e-filed my taxes through Credit Karma. I can confirm that it took about six days to receive both my state and federal returns.